# Eclipse: can't save file - 'negative time' error

Tags: eclipse

When I save a file in Eclipse, it throws an error: "save all failed - negative time".

Can anyone help?

Comment: You can check log detail in the "Error Log" view.

Comment: thank you for your answer,i delete the project that cause problems.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Don't know if you solved your problem, but putting an answer here in case someone else stumbles onto this.

I see a similar sounding problem [here](http://us.generation-nt.com/answer/bulk-change-file-modification-dates-help-199380491.html).

Seems like the file you want to save has a bad timestamp. Try touching the file with another editor to update the timestamp, then see if it will work in Eclipse.

Comment: Is there a bug report for this in eclipse, anybody knows? It shouldn't be that hard to fix.

Comment: I have the same problem.I just cancel the selection of "Copy to workspace",then it works.

Answer (score 5):

As Tim said, my error was an XML with no Date Modified. Easiest way to do it is open the file with error with notepad and re-save it.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Tim, r_19

**[My Solution]**

- Step 1: Download "SetFileDate v2.0"
- Step 2: After install, choose Tab "Scan Folder(s)" select folder Project Soure
- Step 3: Click Button "Modify date(s)"
- Step 4: Refresh your Project in Eclip
- Step 5: DONE

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, tried editing the file it was talking about.  Turned out to be some graphics files in my resources that I downloaded had creation dates of year 1601.