# Errors running builder 'Java Builder' Negative time

Tags: java

Has anyone run into this issue and if so how do you fix it? This has been plaguing me for a while now.

Here is the full error:

`Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 
'Java Builder' on project 'Alarm Klock'.
Negative time`

Comment: It looks like a file in your project has a bad timestamp. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10172694/eclipse-cant-save-file-negative-time-error

Comment: @cremersstijn -- That worked if you would put that down as an answer I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a file in your project has a bad timestamp. See  [Eclipse: can't save file - 'negative time' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10172694/eclipse-cant-save-file-negative-time-error) for a similar issue